# Vulnerable CRLF environment

Tags: php, http, java

I'm looking for a vulnerable CRLF environment. So far I've tested PHP and JSP.

In PHP 5.6, `header` gives you a warning if you try to insert a newline:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in
```

In Java 1.8 + Tomcat 7.0.78, `response.setHeader` replaces the `\r\n` symbols with spaces.

So, starting from which version did Java and PHP fix the CRLF vulnerability?

Comment: There are many  [CRLF injection vulnerabilities](https://www.google.com/search?q=crlf+injection+cve). Which one are you referring too?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich the `header` function in PHP and `response.setHeader` method in Java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- PHP - 4.2.1 - [CVE](http://www.cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2002-1783) - Or see the Anders answer.
- TOMCAT - Before 6.0.37 / 7.0.30 - [CVE](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2012-3544)

Since CRLF Injection is directly related to HTTP response splitting attacks, I recommend you to read the question I asked, [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/161878/combining-http-smuggling-trace-http-method). The answer was above my expectation.

**EDIT**

For some reasons, I needed to test some PHP header injections today. @Anders is right, the exploit I linked in the CVE is much more difficult to execute than the exploit stated in his answer below.

Comment: The CVE you link to for PHP is related to some more obscure exploit. Up until 5.1.2 you could insert newlines right into the header function. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

For PHP, [the changelog in the manual for `header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) has the following to say:

> **5.1.2** This function now prevents more than one header to be sent at once as a protection against header injection attacks.